# How retrieve and display data from a database in a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to display the database content on my windows form by selecting records based on a particular email.

I am using the following code but it is not retrieving it

```
private void editrecordbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyOleDbConnection.Open();
    string query = string.Format("select Email from login where Email='{0}'", editrecordtextBox.Text);
    OleDbCommand vcom1 = new OleDbCommand(query, MyOleDbConnection.vcon);
    OleDbDataReader reader = vcom1.ExecuteReader();
    //int check = vcom1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    string email = (string)reader["Email"];
    if (email == editrecordtextBox.Text)
    {
        if (editrecordtextBox.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            EmailReturn = editrecordtextBox.Text;
            FinalEdit er = new FinalEdit();
            this.Close();
            er.Show();
            MyOleDbConnection.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No record selected");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email-Id");
    }
    MyOleDbConnection.Close();
}
```

Please help me understand what is wrong with it and if I am looking at this approach in the right manner.

Comment: Did you debug your code? What are `EmailReturn` and `FinalEdit` classes also? And be aware of [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I want my email to be `';drop table login;`

Comment: @spender YOU EVIL! =)

Comment: More SQL injection info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The `OleDbDataReader` has a method `Read`. `Read` will return true as long as there is data available.

Normally you would use it like this:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    // work with the current row of data    
}
```

Since you never call `Read`, you don't retrieve any data. You need to call Read at least once to move it to the first row of data that is returned by your query.

Another important issue with your code has to do with [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You are manually creating your query string which is very dangerous. You really need to switch to Parameterized Queries. Here is a good blog post that explains how to use those: [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: @user2273995 Did it help in fixing your problem? :)